# How to confirm a successful uploaded object in google storage with if statement in PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I use the code below to upload a file to google storage which is successful. pls how do I use if statement to confirm it's successful like:

```
<?php

    function upload_object($bucketName, $objectName, $source){    
       $storage = new StorageClient();
       $file = fopen($source, 'r');
       $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
       $object = $bucket->upload($file, ['name' => $objectName);    
          printf('Uploaded %s to gs://%s/%s' . PHP_EOL, basename($source), $bucketName, $objectName);
     }
upload_object($bucketName, $objectName, $source);

    if ($object->exists() === false) {
        echo "The object '{$object->name}' does not exist.";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't know `google-cloud-storage`, but just return the status from the function and test that:

```
function upload_object($bucketName, $objectName, $source){    
   $storage = new StorageClient();
   $file = fopen($source, 'r');
   $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
   $object = $bucket->upload($file, ['name' => $objectName]);    

   return $object->exists();
}

$result = upload_object($bucketName, $objectName, $source);

if ($result === false) {
   echo "The object '{$object->name}' does not exist.";
} else {
   printf('Uploaded %s to gs://%s/%s' . PHP_EOL, basename($source), $bucketName, $objectName);
}
```

After searching a bit it seems that you probably need to use `GoogleException`:

```
use Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\GoogleException;

try {
    $object = $bucket->upload($file, ['name' => $objectName]);
} catch (GoogleException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();  //or something
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for taking your time but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for an exception of type `Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\GoogleException` to determine if there was an issue during the process. If no exception is thrown, your object will have been successfully uploaded.

```
use Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\GoogleException;

try {
    $object = $bucket->upload('mydata', [
        'name' => 'test.txt'
    ]);
} catch (GoogleException $ex) {
    $ex->getMessage(); // handle the failure
}
```

Source: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/issues/666